# Why does the integral of $E\psi(x)dx$ go to zero around the the delta function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, calculus, dirac-delta-distributions

My lecturer writes:

[image]

Firstly, I assume the term with a second derivative is, well, exactly that - a second derivative and therefore intended to be $\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2}$ and not $\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx}$.

For context, this wave function is for the potential $V(x)=-\alpha\delta(x)$.

I would be enormously grateful if someone might explain why the integral on the RHS goes to zero due to "continuity".

Now, I understand that in the limit $\epsilon$ approaches zero, a definite integral between $-\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ will go to zero, but then the terms on the left would also go to zero - and they don't, as shown in the next line of his solution...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the LHS is nonzero is quite simple. On the one hand, $$\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\dfrac{df}{dx}dx=f(\epsilon)-f(-\epsilon).$$

The limit as $\epsilon\to 0$ quantifies the discontinuity of $f(x)$ at zero. That is the reason why $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}dx=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\bigg(\dfrac{d\psi}{dx}\bigg|_{x=0^+}-\dfrac{d\psi}{dx}\bigg|_{x=0^-}\bigg).$$

On the other hand, $$\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \delta(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$$

and there is no dependence on $\epsilon$ whatsoever, so the limit is trivial. The thing is that the integral of $\delta(x)f(x)$ over *any* interval $[a,b]$ containing $0$ is $f(0)$, with no further dependence on $a$ and $b$. So that is the reason why $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}-\delta(x)\alpha \psi(x)=-\alpha \psi(0).$$

Now about the RHS. Since $\psi(x)\in \mathbb{C}$ let us write $\psi(x)=f(x)+ig(x)$, which reduces the problem to functions $f,g:[-\epsilon,\epsilon]\to \mathbb{R}$. Continuity implies these functions are bounded on $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ and therefore we may bound the integrals in terms of the length of the interval which is $2\epsilon$ and the minimum and maximum values of the functions $$2\epsilon m_f \leq \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon f(x)dx \leq 2\epsilon M_f,\quad 2\epsilon m_g \leq \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon g(x)dx \leq 2\epsilon M_g.$$

As $\epsilon \to 0$ we therefore conclude that these integrals vanish and therefore so does that of $\psi(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer - super helpful

Comment: @NGodrich If you think this answer is helpful, consider to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

"Continuity" is the wrong term there.  It'd probably be better to say that "assuming that $\psi(x)$ is *finite* at 0, the integral from $-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$ will go to zero as $\epsilon \to 0$."  The only way that this integral can remain finite as $\epsilon \to 0$ is if $\psi(x)$ itself has "delta-function-like" behavior at $x= 0$.  But if it does, it will not be square integrable ($\int [\delta(x)]^2 \, dx$ is not well defined) and so we can rule out that possibility.

I will freely admit that I'm playing fast and loose with the mathematics in the above equation;  a more rigourous analysis is probably possible.  But hopefully the above gives some intuition as to why this statement is made in this derivation.

Answer (score 0):

So your equation is:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}\left[
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left\{\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2}\right\}
-\alpha\delta(x)\psi(x)
\right]dx
=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}
E\psi(x)dx$$

We can factor out the constants, and also split the sum on the left side:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}
\underbrace{\int_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2}dx}
_{=\left.\frac{d\psi(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=+\epsilon}
  -\left.\frac{d\psi(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=-\epsilon}}
-\alpha\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}
\underbrace{\int_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}\delta(x)\psi(x)dx}_{=\psi(0)}
=E\ \underbrace{\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}\psi(x)dx}_{=0}$$

Here we used:

- for the first integral, the [theorem how to calculate an integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Second_theorem),
  (Note that we did *not* assume $\frac{d\psi(x)}{dx}$
  to be continuous. If we we did so, then this integral
  would be zero.)
- for the second integral, the definition of the [Dirac-$\delta$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions),
- for the third integral, the fact that $\psi(x)$ is continuous

So we are left with
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(
\left.\frac{d\psi(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=+\epsilon}
-\left.\frac{d\psi(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=-\epsilon}
\right)-\alpha\psi(0)=0$$